# Calculating area with definite integral where there isn't superior function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

How would you find the area between $y=2x$, $y = -x^2 + 6x$ and **the axis $x$**?

I thought I would use the formula of

$$S = \lvert \int_a^b(f(x) - g(x))dx \rvert$$

And then
$$S = \lvert \int_0^4(f(x) - g(x))dx \rvert$$
However, there isn't actually a *superior function* and *lower function*; one over the other, being $f(x)$ the *superior function*.

---

Do I need to separate the area in two parts:?

- Area of triangle.
- Area of function.

Or how?

Comment: Between $x=0$ to $x=4$ you have $-x^2+6x>2x$. Also [Answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+2x+and+-x^2%2B6x). BTW, if your'e taking absolute value you don't have to worry about which function is higher.

Comment: How do you see that and how does that help? In addition, I didn't learn inequalities in integrals and calculating areas.

Comment: @Galc127 You forgot my area is between both functions **and** axis $x$.

Comment: You are correct, I missed the $x$ axis. I didn't use inequalities in integrals, only showed which function is higher in $(0,4)$. Look at the following [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot[{{y%3D-x^2%2B6x},{y%3D2x},{y%3D0},{x%3D4}}]). We need to evaluate two areas, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, finding intersection between functions$$-x^2+6x=2x\Rightarrow 0=x^2-4x=x(x-4)\Rightarrow \underline{x_1=0,x_2=4}$$

Second, find the intersection of functions with $x$ axis\begin{align*}&2x=0\Rightarrow x=0\\ &-x^2+6x=0\Rightarrow -x(x-6)=0\Rightarrow x_1=0,x_2=6\end{align*}

Third, draw the following graph

$\hskip2in$ [image: Graph]

We Have two areas to compute$$S=S_1+S_2=\int\limits_{0}^{4}2x\text{d}x+\int\limits_{4}^{6}-x^2+6x\text{d}x=\Big.x^2\Big\vert_{0}^{4}+\left.\left(3x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\right\vert_{4}^{6}=16+\frac{28}{3}=\frac{76}{3}$$

Comment: As I discovered a bit late, correct answer. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to find where the parabola and $x$ axis intersect: $0 = -x^2 + 6x$, hence $x = 0$ and $x = 6$. We evaluate $$\int_{0}^{6} (6x - x^2)\, dx = 36.$$ But now, we should subtract the area which is not bounded by $x$ axis, i.e., $$\int_{0}^{4} (4x - x^2)\, dx = \frac {32} {3}$$ to have $$\text{Area} = 36 - \frac {32} {3} = \frac {76} {3}.$$

Comment: It is actually not what we need to find. You didn't include the $x$ axis.

Comment: @Galc127 I had included it. Please read through better. I said $y = 0$. And this reflected in the fact that I used $f (x) - g (x) > 0$.

Comment: It is not the area we are asked to find, try to draw it and look for the area that is between the function and the axis. I have posted an answer with a graph below.

Comment: The region you're integrating here is all above the $x$-axis, that's true, but it's entirely contained between the other two curves. The $x$ axis is not any useful part of the boundary of that region. There is another region below those two curves that does have a long boundary defined by the $x$-axis, and is evidently the region desired.

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. I am sorry, I missed such an obvious point. This is obvious even without a graph. Just intersect the parabola with $y = 0$ to get $x = 0$ and $x = 6$. Integrate the $-x^2 + 6x$ to get $36$. Then subtract $32/3$ to get $76/3$. I should be really stupid for arguing over something I was wrong.

Comment: @NimaBavari No problem, few people recognize a mistake right away, and many would take much longer than you did.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to plot the functions to see what region you would be integrating.

The function $y=−x^2+6x$ is a parabola that crosses the $x$-axis at $(0,0)$,
rises to its vertex at $(3,9)$, and the crosses back below the
$x$-axis at $(6,0)$.  So there is already a region enclosed between this
curve and the $x$-axis.

The function $y=2x$ cuts that region in two pieces.
As it happens, $y=2x$, $y=−x^2+6x$, and the $x$-axis 
all intersect at one point,
so one of the pieces is entirely between $y=2x$ and $y=−x^2+6x$
above the $x$-axis, so the $x$-axis is not needed as a boundary there;
the other piece is below both $y=2x$ and $y=−x^2+6x$,
and is bounded below by the $x$-axis.

So you have some choices. You can let $f(x)$ be the piecewise
function such that $f(x) = 2x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 4$
and $f(x)=−x^2+6x$ for $4 \leq x \leq 6$,
and let $g(x)$ be the function $x=0$.
(Yes, the $x$-axis is the graph of a function.)
Then you will probably want to use two integrals,
one for each piece of $f(x)$.

An alternative is to integrate over $y$ from $y=0$ to $y=8$,
using $f(y)=3 + \sqrt{9-y}$ and $g(y) = \frac12 x$.
Personally, I think the piecewise function is easier to work with.

Comment: Nice answer, (+1).